# Ubuntu webserver misconfiguration

Tags: ubuntu, web-server, vps, apache2

We are trying to move our hosted website to our own VPS. 
I asked the company where we host the server to set up the webserver because it's running Ubuntu and I'm not a Linux expert and didn't wanted to mess up our ERP and other softwares.

They did set up the webserver but something is really wrong with it.

First of all there were permission problems which was partialy resolved but when I uploaded the website (Presta Shop) almost nothing worked. The frontpage gave http 500 error, on the back end the UTF-8 characters were messed up, the installed modules didn't show up etc...

So I started to investigate, the http 500 is because presta shop does not see the theme folder. The folder exists and the permissions are ok, so thats not the problem.

Next I reninstalled the Presta Shop theme and modules.
The theme works but the newly created theme and module folders are nowhere to be found in the document root. At least with the FTP user access.

I checked the Presta Shop configuration and the Presta Shop sees a different doc root path than the FTP.

The path I can access via FTP/SFTP or SSH is /sql/www_html/ and Presta sees /var/www/html/ but there is no www folder in /var

Whats going on? Why is Presta seeing a different path? And where are the newly created theme, module folders?

But the bigest question is how can I fix it? 
Is this an Apache misconfig or something else?

Comment: You are using a non-standard path for the webserver. I think it might be SELinux, a security mechanism that doesn't allow Apache to read outside /var/www. Look into the logs in /var/log/apparmor. You can easily adjust apparmor under /etc/apparmor, there is a file for apache and it is self eplanatory.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not good enough to help you much with that much info.  If you could give some install steps or a link to the steps you were following, I think that would help a lot.

That being said, I would probably try to make sure I can:

```
 1. check apache configuration `vim
/etc/apache2/sites-available/prestashop.conf`
 2. make sure you're sym-linked from sites-available to sites-enabled
 3. `ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/prestashop.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/prestashop.conf`
 4. then `mv` or `cp -R` the files to `/var/www`
 5. `service apache2 restart`
 6. `mkdir -p /var/www/prestashop && mv /sql/www_html/prestashop/ /var/www/prestashop/`
 7. `chown www-data:www-data -R /var/www/prestashop/`
```

Those last 2 were actually from a tutorial I found just to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious in the answer.  Good thing I checked.  Here's the link, if you haven't already seen it.  I pass those on 'cause it sounds like they're normal and haven't been done on your box(es).
[Link to tutorial for steps 6 and 7](https://www.rosehosting.com/blog/how-to-install-prestashop-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-vps/)

I hope that helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check it tomorrow, because my ISP is down for maintenance and I don't think I should do this from mobile :)